# How to fadeIn text stored in a variable when clicking a button, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, text, fadein

I am trying to fadeIn some text which is stored in a variable that I want to show when a button is clicked. The code below works for the showing part but I can't figure out how to make it fadeIn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Fade in text example</title>
</head>
<body>  

    <div><button id ="button">Click to show text</button></div><br />
    <div id="txtDiv"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var txt = 'Show this stored text.';
            $('#button').on('click', function() {
                $('#txtDiv').text(txt);
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var txt = 'Show this stored text.';
        $('#txtDiv').hide();
        $('#button').on('click', function() {              
          $('#txtDiv').text(txt);
          $('#txtDiv').fadeIn( 600 );
        });
    });
</script>
```